# Distributing Play! Framework jobs

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1, jobs

I have a play! app that runs a certain numbers of jobs. But the problem is, when we need a higher load on the server, we multiply the number of instance, thus our jobs are executed on every Play! servers.
So I need to distribute those crons, but I don't really know where to start looking.
I guess I'd need the equivalent of [Kue](http://learnboost.github.io/kue/) (that is for Node.JS), but don't know anything for Java, and even less for Play!

Do you have any recommendations ?

Answer (score 4):

You could try to use [Akka Cluster Singleton](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/cluster-singleton.html) pattern for that. You can then send messages to that actor via a [Scheduler](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/scheduler.html) and you are done!

Remember that Play is built on top of Akka. That's powerful!

Answer (score 0):

Akka is probably a cleaner solution but a quick way is to add "instance.id=1" or some such to your application.conf for only one of your instances. Then you can check for this in the Global object and kick off your jobs,

```
public void onStart(...)
{
     Integer instanceId = Play.application().configuration().getInt("instance.id");
     if (instanceId == 1)
     {
          ... start jobs ...
     }
}
```